# checking for a certain character in mysql field data, and replacing it with another character

Tags: mysql

The number of rows to be updated are so many. 
so i am trying to :

1) replace every fieldname that has a " "  with a "_",

2) replace every fieldname that has a "\'" with a "*",

3) replace every fieldname that has a "\"" with a "*".

is it possible to do it using only mysql, so that i don't have to loop through and manually update each mysql row using PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE tablename SET somecol = REPLACE(somecol, ' ', '_');
UPDATE tablename SET somecol = REPLACE(somecol, '\'', '*');
UPDATE tablename SET somecol = REPLACE(somecol, '"', '*');
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Comment: thanks a million mate!! 

Worked prefectly!  

However, is it posible to bundle the three queries into one?

Comment: You can concatentate the REPLACE function: UPDATE tablename SET somecol = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(somecol, ' ', '_'),'\'', '*'), '"', '*')));

Comment: Wow! it worked!  Although i had to remove the last 2 brackets.
thank you so much Alex!

Comment: A quick one. Rows with leading and trailing spaces are also being affected. (by the way, i am first importing my data from a .txt file, then running that function you gave me). How can I first TRIM the rows, then use the function : UPDATE tablename SET somecol = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(somecol, ' ', '_'),'\'', ''), '"', '');

Comment: Type the words "mysql trim" into your favorite search engine.